# How to find shortest path between two nodes using struct::graph(::op)?

Tags: tcl, path-finding

I have a grid with obstacles and need to find the most attractive polygon between two nodes. The operation will most likely be a bottle-neck so I hope for bagging a reasonably performant implementation early on, and still have a portable solution (i.e. no C, yet). I'd love to do an OpenCL solution as late game but gotta get there first.

I'm using `struct::graph` for a number of problems already and thought I could use it one more time for this one. Reading the documentation about [graph](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/graph.html#67) and [op](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/graphops.html#subsection1) it seems like the problem is already solved but it eludes me how to actually use the APIs.

The problem is by design simplified. There is a finite rectangular grid (30x30 tops) where each cell is a node in the graph. Each node has axis-aligned edges to other nodes in the grid as long as there are no obstacles along the way, typically ends of already existing polygons. Edge cost is lower for longer edges, making many turns (stairs) less attractive for the path finding algorithm. (There are also other heuristics affecting the edge cost.)

Assuming I have filled `struct::graph` with above, how do I find *the* shortest path from node A to any of the set of nodes B (many if connecting to hypergraph)?

---

**Progress so far:** Many of the op APIs seem to return shortest path to *all* nodes in graph which is not what I want, though I could use it until I find a better way. Assuming I can modify graph in a `walk` cmd I could make some simpler on-the-fly pruning, but the docs do not indicate this as a possibility.

And if it turns out struct::graph is inherently (too) slow I'd be happy to patch it into shape. Just need to know what I'm about to use first...

Comment: You might find some inspiration here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm and particularly here https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Tcl

Comment: An example using struct::graph::op -- https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm#Tcl